# Fastest-validator require one of keys

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an nodeJS app using fastest-validator. I want to have a schema that requires one on the given validations.

I already write a validator that makes both keys optional.

The input is an array of objects like the example below.

```
[
 {
  url: "https://test.com/url",
  index: 0
 },
 {
  thumbnail: "https://test.com/url",
  index: 1
 },
]
```

I want to validate the index and (URL or thumbnail).